# HHVM : What are the consequence for getting Failed Calling MemcachedSessionModule::gc()

Tags: php, garbage-collection, memcached, hhvm

I have configured HHVM 3.70. Here is my php.ini for HHVM

```
; php options
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
memcached.sess_prefix = "memc.sess.key."

; hhvm specific 
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
```

I have looked it up and it has something to do with the garbage collection. There is also an issue opened against it at https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5034.

I am getting intermittent errors for losing data in session. But I am unsure if that is caused by this HHVM issue. What are the consequences for getting this Failed Calling MemcachedSessionModule::gc()?

Thanks